# how do you read all the bytes that come on a tcp connection?

Tags: tcp, redis, go

After you establish a connection and you want to read the bytes coming from the connection, how can you read all the bytes? From what I tried, I can read until it reaches a delimiter like a line break. But how is it possible to get everything including the line breaks? I'm trying to make a redis client in Go and the protocol separates results with \r\n, so in this case Buffer.ReadLine, or Buffer.ReadSlice didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read all bytes from a Reader (like your TCP connection), you can use [`ioutil.ReadAll`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll), which reads until an `EOF` is sent from the other side or an error occurs.

Please note that there are already some [redis clients](http://redis.io/clients/#Go) for go.

Comment: FYI: the Go Redis client *officially* recommended is [Redigo](https://github.com/garyburd/redigo) according to http://redis.io/clients (see the ★).

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer, pointing to that list of clients.

Comment: @nemo I am curious, How is reading to an EOF the correct thing to do when talking to a redis-server? The redis-server could send any stream of bytes as long as it complies with the protocol. The redis-server can only respond with any of the 5 different data types as defined by the redis protocol. I am just confused, sending an EOF is **not** part of the protocol specification. Thus, reading up to a EOF doesn't seem to make sense to me because that might never be sent.

Comment: I feel the correct thing to do is, if you know what type of response you are expecting (because you know what command you are sending because you are the redis client sending commands to redis), then the correct thing to do is, read until the response you expect ends. In the case of RESP simple strings, Errors and integers, stop reading from the connection when `\r\n` is reached. In the case of a Bulk String or RESP Arrays, then keep reading until the prefixed lengths (i.e. type-length value scheme) says to stop reading. I think that is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Unless of course, you can convince me otherwise that your solution is the correct one.

Comment: Note: also that the redis-server might be implemented in any language.

Comment: The thing I am still unsure of is wether `EOF` is something part of TCP and that go net handles by itself or how do I know `EOF` was sent from the server informing the end of the whole response. It seems to me that the redis-server might be sending as many bytes as it can using some kind of Write(bytes) method, that specifies how many bytes were actually written to the socket. If it didn't send all the bytes it wanted to send, it might retry writing to the TCP socket and then, how would the redis-client know about the end of the actual message if for each write, an EOF is sent?