# Functionality to catch arriving connection on tcp port

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

I have an application running on TCP port 4000 and I want to perform some verification on the IPs which are connecting with port 4000. So, I already have the verification API which is basically a post API. I am looking forward to calling this API whenever any new client IP connects with port 4000.
Is this possible in Linux in any language?

Comment: Do you have a source code of application listening for TCP on 4000 port? Or you have external application running and listening on 4000 port? If you have a source code then you can fetch address IP after accepted connection and perform the check

Comment: That's an external application

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you need the client's IP Address that is connecting to your server on port 4000. You then want to send that IP to your API via an HTTP POST and depending on the result you will accept or drop the client.

It seems like the only thing you are really missing is the `getpeername` syscall. No matter the language you are using, when you accept or create a TCP connection a socket is created in the OS and data is sent to and from it and your application. Once this socket is created you can query the OS to tell you what is the remote IP address/TCP port in the connection via the `getpeername` syscall. In 'C' there is a function that does this for you called [getpeername](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html). If you are using another language you may have another function or the data could already be gathered and placed in a data structure at conenction time (in Go you can just call `Conn.RemoteAddr()`).

Knowing this you can do the following:

- Accept the client connection, but do not read/write any data
- Grab the client's IP Address from the `getpeername` syscall
- Send the IP Address to your API via a POST
- Read and Write data to the client if API returns authorized responce, else drop the connection

Comment: Hi, @Liam Thank you for such a helpful answer. Can we use this method for the tcp port which is used by external application? as we don't have code to access for the application.

Comment: In that case you would likely be better writing a proxy application that the client connects to, you perform the actions mentioned, and upon authorization the proxy makes a connection to the original server and forwards traffic to/from it and the client. Your need to use a POST API call prevents other more efficient options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090690/how-to-write-a-proxy-in-go-golang-using-tcp-connections

Comment: Actually you could write an XDP Socket application but that is much more technical.

Comment: @stark the SCM_RIGHTS mechanism requires the other application to listen on a shared unix socket though, correct? Which won't work because the code is not available on the original server. Or can this mechanism really fake out the typical `accept(...)` server logic in the original server?

Comment: Yeah.  There's no simple way in TCP.  Proxy is probably best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tcpdump` to listening for a new connection on 4000 port and take action on each stdout line from `tcpdump` and using sed to extract address IP. Then you can use for example `xargs` to make action.

To filter for `tcpdump` you can use

```
tcpdump -n 'tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn != 0 and port 4000 and inbound'
```